# UILabel has border in some case

Tags: ios, iphone

There is a line appear at the end of the label. Not sure why it comes. Some time in landscape and some time in portrait. It is in consistent issue. What could be the issue? In image attached there is a border shown if I change the orientation it disappears.

[image]

Following is my implementation

```
                            @implementation MCLabel

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        btnSeeMore = [MCButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btnSeeMore setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [btnSeeMore setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self addSubview:btnSeeMore];
        [btnSeeMore setHidden:YES];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This is how I add the label

```
 MCLabel *lblRecord = [[MCLabel alloc] init];
                                [vwRow addSubview:lblRecord];
                                [lblRecord setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
                                [lblRecord setTextAlignment:column.alignmentOfObject];
                                [lblRecord setFont:column.fontOfObject];
                                [lblRecord setStrObjID:column.linkName];
                                [lblRecord setBackgroundColor:column.clrBackground];
[lblRecord setFrame:column.frame];
                [lblRecord setText:column.strData];
```

Comment: how do you set label?

Comment: Please put some code or some more description about your layout. in this details it is hard to get the issue

Comment: I don't think it is a border of UILabel, it must be some `UIView` that is blocked by `UILabel`.

Comment: if label's bg is white _and_ label's superview's bg is gray _and_ your label's frame has non integer value this error can occur.

Comment: @MohitPopat added snippet